# how to get text from other page in php

Tags: php

I want to get text data in my php page from other website, 
I can give input url and pass post parameters to page but when it returns result I want that to get in my page and want to arrange with my style .

can any one help me with this.

other website's output page is not in `.html` format .

input url

```
www.website.com/xxx/xxxx/xxx/history
```

passing one **POST** parameter

output url

```
www.website.com/xxx/xxxx/xxx/history/Print
```

=====================================
**`UPDATE 1`**

actually real site is

```
http://14.139.122.69:8099/instinfo/smark/Grad/HistroyFind
```

when i enter enrollment no and submit,it passes one parameter `enroll` with POST methos, and then redirects to this page

```
http://14.139.122.69:8099/instinfo/smark/GradHistroy/Print
```

I want to get data from this page and print on my page.

Comment: You're looking for `$_GET` if you want it passed through the URL

Comment: So you want to get data from another website and display it on your website, with your style? I assume you've got permission from the other website to do so?

Comment: What about making your question more clear?

Comment: The question is not quite clear. Could you explain what you're trying to do in detail?

Comment: have you tried http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php?

Comment: @andrewsi don't need to get permission, it's allowed.

Comment: @Dave can i get particular tag from that page ? like <div> with specific class or <td> with class.

Comment: if the div hold something unique to it like an ID or a Class, then you can parse the returned content and just preg_match everything between a div open and close

Comment: let me try, thanks for tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use curl()

for example:

```
<?php
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.website.com/xxx/xxxx/xxx/history");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

sample code from http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php

Comment: this is giving whole page, what if i want only some part of that page, like some particular tag with specific class ?

Comment: if you want some part of that page. you can use preg_match or preg_match_all functions.

sorry, i'm not good in regular expression so i cannot help you to show those preg_match pattern.